# How to add to a counter using decisions and input

Tags: python

I have tried for the past hour to make this program. The aim of the program is to record the preference of food for 15 people and count and display the total at the end. Each person can only choose 1 food. Here is where I'm stuck. None of this code seems to work(add to the counters). If anybody can help or send me the correct code it would be greatly appreciated:)

```py
#Choices of food for the customers

meatplate_1 = 0 

fishplate_2 = 0

vegetableplate_3 = 0

#Decision making as input data

for i in range (15):
    num = int(input("What do you want for lunch?"))

if num == 1 :
    meatplate + 1

print(meatplate_1)
```

Comment: I don't see a variable named `meatplate` defined anywhere, did you mean `meatplate_1`?  And if you did, `.append` is a `list` method, but `meatplate_1` is an `int`.

Comment: Also, num is an int that you keep overwriting, but then your if statement checking the value of num is outside of the for loop. I think you want the if statement inside the loop.

Comment: is it like customers can order meat, fish or veg? they can choose any 1 of 3. at the end, for 15 people, you need to display how many meat, fish, veg orders were placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @0x5453 in comments, you should increment meatplate_1 variable.
And, If condition should come inside for loop, increment should be done by += operator.
You can refer below code.

```py
#Choices of food for the customers

meatplate_1 = 0 

fishplate_2 = 0

vegetableplate_3 = 0

#Decision making as input data

for i in range (15):
    num = int(input("What do you want for lunch?"))
    if num == 1 :
        meatplate_1+=1
    elif num==2:
        fishplate_2+=1
    elif num==3:
        vegetableplate_3+=1
    else:
        pass

print(meatplate_1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. Hopefully, in the future I can become as good as you and help other people.